# AndroidStudio/Gradle stuck building application

Tags: android, android-studio

When I tried to compile this class in Android Studio 3.1.1 using the Gradle **build** task the compiler gets stuck; the build processes never stop.

```
package com.callforward.testsharedmemory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    }
}
```

I know the problem is caused by the way the array is being initialized; I just don't know why.

Did anybody see this and have an explanation for it?

Comment: Gradle takes forever to load if you have low end hardware or it might be a bug in Android Studio itself. Try restarting your IDE and do it again.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

(if on mac) Android Studio -> preferences... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Check the 'Offline work' under 'Global Gradle settings'

It will reduce 90% gradle build time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Studio 3.1 on MAC. I build your source code OK.

I think memory that you assign for process of Android Studio is not enough. You try increase memory for process Android Studio.

My Android Studio: file gradle.properties

**org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m**